# XMLDoc for Delphi unit name

Tags: delphi, xml-documentation, delphi-10.3-rio

Is it possible to document unit purpose in Delphi using `<summary>` XMLDoc tag? How?

I've tried put summary both before `unit`:

```
/// <summary> Unit purpose: test </summary>
unit Test;
```

and after:

```
unit Test;
/// <summary> Unit purpose: test </summary>
```

Both approaches gives nothing. Checked by hovering over the unit name in the other unit. At the same time hovering works for other identifiers in the same units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Embarcadero's documentation:

[XML Documentation Comments](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML_Documentation_Comments)

> You can use the following elements in XML DOC comments:
>
> `<summary>`
>
> A summary of the target **function or class**

So no, it does not appear that you can apply a `<summary>` to the unit as a whole.

Comment: Indeed, it also works for properties and for types which aren't classes, like records, enumerations, simple types (like `type MyInt = type Integer`) etc., so this remark in the documentation is not quite accurate. However, if Serhii has tried to put the XML comment before a unit and it didn't work, this very likely means that the answer to this question is "No" (at least in the OP's version of Delphi). So really, this Q is more of a Delphi feature request aimed at Embarcadero! :)